# Achartengine - first x value offset from grid

Tags: achartengine

Is there a possibility to move x values from y axis? Like in the following pic
[image]

(Left chart is wrong without x-offset, right is correct one)

Comment: Simply, set renderer.setXAxisMin(minDate-81300000/16). Note minDate represents your first x-axis value(time) in millis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the X axis minimum visible point:

```
renderer.setXAxisMin(someDatetimeInMillis);
```